# recursively convert a list

Tags: java, recursion

Need some help writing a recursive method in java. I have the following class -

```
public class Node {
... 
    private List<Node> children;
---
}
```

There are two types of Nodes. Type A and Type B. Input to the method will be a List that looks like this -

```
1 - Type A
2 - Type B
3 - Type B
4 - Type B
5 - Type A
6 - Type B
7 - Type B
8 - Type A
9 - Type B
10 - Type B

private void convertList(List<Node> nodes) {

}
```

I am writing a method that will convert the list to look like -

```
1
children 2, 3, 4, 5
                  children - 6, 7, 8
                                   children - 9, 10
```

I can convertList  iteratively by starting the loop from  bottom till I reach the root. I am trying to do it recursively but simply can't get the logic straight. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: how do you define "convert"?

Comment: Suggestion: have your `convertList` return a new `List` instead of `void`.  If you try to do everything by manipulating the existing list, you will go crazy.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that you have a working iterative solution, and want to convert it to a recursive one? Like any of the ways that Google gives for a search query such as "Convert loop to recursion Java"?

Comment: Is the idea that each Type A should have the remaining elements as it's children?

Comment: x23 - That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hint for your method :

if node B then add all nodes in the list as sibling nodes,
if node A then add all node in the list as child.

It will be smthg like the following :

```
private void convertList(List<Node> nodes) {

    List<Node> newNodesList = new ArrayList<Nodes>()

    node=last node
    // you will have to do smthg specific for 1st call
    // else

    if (nodetype==A){
        //add nodes to children of A
        //add A to newNodes
    }
    else // assuming only A and B
    {
        //newNodesList=nodes except last
        //add node to the newNodesList
    }
    return convertList(newNodesList);
}
```

I think it is te way you have to think this.

And find too the way to stop recursion.

Comment: I am working on a similar algo. I was thinking the solution was simpler and I was confusing myself a lot.  Will mark this answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this solution

```
    private List<Node> convertList(List<Node> children, int i, LinkedList<Node> newNodeList) {
    i -= 1;
    if (!(i >= 0)) {
        return newNodeList;
    }
    Node node = children.get(i);
    if (node.getType() == "B") {
        newNodeList.addFirst(node);
    } else if (node.getType() == "A") {
        children.remove(i);
        node.setChildren(new ArrayList<>(newNodeList));
        newNodeList.clear();
        newNodeList.addFirst(node);
    }
    return convertList(children, i, newNodeList);
```

}

To call this method do -

```
allNodes.remove(firstNode);
LinkedList<Node> newNodeList = new LinkedList<>();
convertList(allNodes, allNodes.size(), newNodeList);
firstNode.setChildren(newNodeList)
```